# How to avoid collapsing of absolute positioned images in a fixed height container on all devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, responsive

I have positioned a few images in a container with a fixed height. On my laptop it looks good. But as I switch to other screen widths, the images collapse. Am I supposed to give the container a different height for every existing screen widths in CSS media queries, or there is a more universal solution? I need to solve it with positioning, since the images are very randomly positioned in the plan, but I want it to be proper on all devices.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="img-container">
       <img src="img/img-1.jpg" class="positioned-img-1" alt="img-1">
       <img src="img/img-2.jpg" class="positioned-img-2" alt="img-1">
       <img src="img/img-3.jpg" class="positioned-img-3" alt="img-3">
       <img src="img/img-4.jpg" class="positioned-img-4" alt="img-4">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    height: 160vh;
    position: relative;
}

.positioned-img-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 46%;
}

.positioned-img-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 6%;
    max-width: 40%;
}

.positioned-img-3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    left: 14%;
    max-width: 40%;
}

.positioned-img-4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    right: 15%;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `object-fit: cover` to your images.

Comment: Sorry, in fact not images are positioned, but figures, in which are the images and figcaptions.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: But please understand, that the images are very randomly positioned in the design plan, which I have to follow.